# How to Edit Two Model in one View EntityFramework.dll error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This my Code

Model

```cs
public class ViewModelRequestPurchaseItem
{
   public List<RequestPurchase> RequestPurchases  { get; set; }
   public List<RequestPurchaseItem> RequestPurchaseItems { get; set; }
}
```

View

```cs
@using EFMySQLCardTest.Models
@model EFMySQLCardTest.Models.ViewModelRequestPurchaseItem
```

Controller

```cs
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "RequestPurchases,RequestPurchaseItems")] ViewModelRequestPurchaseItem viewModelRequestPurchaseItem, string id)
{      
    var requestPurchase = db.RequestPurchase.Where(x => x.RequestPurchaseNumber == id).ToList();     
    var requestPurchaseItem = db.RequestPurchaseItem.Where(x => x.RequestPurchaseNumber == id).OrderBy(x => x.RequestPurchaseItemID).ToList();    
    viewModelRequestPurchaseItem.RequestPurchases = requestPurchase;
    viewModelRequestPurchaseItem.RequestPurchaseItems = requestPurchaseItem;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(viewModelRequestPurchaseItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        this.ExpendErrors();
    }
    return View(viewModelRequestPurchaseItem);
}
```

In this line:

```cs
db.Entry(viewModelRequestPurchaseItem).State = EntityState.Modified
```

the error is:

> viewModelRequestPurchaseItem is not model of parts

Comment: Don't you think error detail is required!!

Comment: sorry i really don't know your means...
can you help me plz..

Comment: What is the error? Which line of code throws error? Is it simple enough to understand!!

Comment: in this line he say viewModelRequestPurchaseItem is not model of  parts
db.Entry(viewModelRequestPurchaseItem).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Also please use the edit link to provide any additional details such as the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: update your question with related error information.

Comment: thanks Mark  i will update  now ^^

Comment: it's possible to transaction DBSet questions !?
cause i just only edit RequestPurchaseItems in view !?

Comment: `viewModelRequestPurchaseItem` is your view model and is not part of the database context. You need to save each `RequestPurchase` and `RequestPurchaseItems` in the collections. But you code makes no sense - why are you assigning the values of `RequestPurchases` and `RequestPurchaseItems` in the POST method to the existing values in your database and completely overriding any values you have edited. And whats the point of saving something which has not changed (you just fetched them from the database). Also remove the pointless `[Bind]` attribute you have.

Comment: yes i'm very confused....
viewModelRequestPurchaseItem  is not my database model
but how can i edit it and to save it's 
thanks u Stephen Muecke

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this code. It looks like you take in your ViewModel from your form, retrieve versions of the items from the database, and then use those database versions and overwrite the data in the ViewModel, then attempt to save the ViewModel data into your database. So, you've essentially written code that ignores user input, gets data from the database, then updates the database with the DB data you just retrieved.

Comment: yes Ellesedil it's true i just Training 
i  want to Edit Two Model in One Views 
i really don't know how to Edit it 
cause my view is 
 @foreach (RequestPurchase item in Model.RequestPurchases)
   {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RequestPurchaseNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.UserAccount)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
wrong  here

Answer (score 1):

`ViewModelRequestPurchaseItem` is your view model and is not part of the database context. You need to save each `RequestPurchase` and `RequestPurchaseItems` in the collections. You current code is also assigning the collections to the current values in the database, wiping out any edits you have made in the view. Your method should be

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModelRequestPurchaseItem model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  foreach (RequestPurchase item in model.RequestPurchases)
  {
    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
  }
  // ditto for RequestPurchaseItems
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: thaks Stephen Mucke^^
I'm try to Edit it

Comment: This is my View 
and wrong here 
@foreach (RequestPurchase item in Model.RequestPurchases)
   {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RequestPurchaseNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.UserAccount)
        </td>
    </tr>
   }

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection. You need a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate` for your types.

Comment: And `DisplayFor()` does not create a form control. You cant edit anything so unclear what you really trying to do. It needs to be `for(int i = 0; i < Model.RequestPurchases.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RequestPurchases[i].RequestPurchaseNumber) .....}`

Comment: i just wanna use it RequestPurchases to display Name and id or~ 
really edit just only RequestPurchasesItem so i really don't know 
how to fix it....help..

Comment: This answer addresses your question. I cant possibly guess what else your trying to do. You need to ask a new question and show the relevant code and explain the issue. But if your only editing `RequestPurchasesItems` then you only need a `foreach (RequestPurchaseItem item in model.RequestPurchaseItems)` in the controller to mark them as modified and save

Comment: sure and  I really appreciate that
can u teach me how to Edit Two or Multiple Model in one view int database ..
i really confusing ..
can u show your Code to me

Comment: You need to ask a NEW question showing what you have tried and what is not working. I'm not going to guess what your trying to do. I have already answer this question correctly.

Comment: thanks Stephen Muecke i will ask new questions but i think i need to 
promote my MVC i am very  appreciate

Comment: 2 questions, 2 correct answers and still you cant be bothered accepting them. Good luck getting any help in the future.